# roblox punch animation not working (no errors)

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I'm trying to create a punch ability in roblox by following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3DdxW5fKZs). I'm not getting any errors, but the punch animation stops in the middle without finishing. Everything else is working though.

I expected the animation to finish all the way to the end but it didnt, even though I tried to edit the wait times of all the task.wait functions.

This is my code, can someone please help me figure out where I went wrong?

```
--gets replicated storage and players
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local players = game:GetService("Players")

--creates cooldown and distance variables
local punchDebounces = {}
local punchDistance = 4
local punchDebounceDuration = 1.2

--creates fuction hit with parameters character(who is getting hit) and damage(how much damage the character is taking)
local function hit(character, damage)
    --takes damage
    character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(damage)
    
    --creates knockback force
    local vf = Instance.new("VectorForce")
    print(character.PrimaryPart)
    vf.Attachment0 = character.HumanoidRootPart.RootAttachment
    vf.Force = Vector3.new(0, 0, 40000)
    vf.Parent = character.PrimaryPart
    
    --creates particle effect for when the character gets hit
    local particle = script.punchParticle:Clone()
    particle.Parent = character.PrimaryPart
    particle:Emit(30)
    
    --waits before getting rid of knockback force
    task.wait(0.03)
    
    --gets rid of knockback force and particle effect if they have not been deleted already
    if vf.Parent ~= nil then
        vf:Destroy()
    end

    task.wait(1)

    if particle.Parent ~= nil then
        particle:Destroy()
    end
end

--creates a function that plays punch animation and triggers remote event "punch"
local function punch(player)
    
    --gets character from player
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local punchDamage = 30
    
    --returns end if it cant find character, it cant find humanoid, the player is dead, or if their punch is still on cooldown
    if character == nil then return end
    if not character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
    if character.Humanoid.Health == 0 then return end
    if punchDebounces[player] then return end
    
    --starts cooldown
    punchDebounces[player] = true
    
     --plays punch animation
    local punchAnimation = character.Humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(script.punch)
    punchAnimation:Play()
    
    --triggers the hit function when animation reaches keyframe "damage"
    punchAnimation.KeyframeReached:Connect(function(keyFrameName)
        
        --returns end as long as animation hasnt reached keyframe "damage"
        if keyFrameName ~= "damage" then
            return
        end
        
        --gets players
        for _, plr in players:GetPlayers() do
            
            --gets character
            local char = plr.Character
            
            --checks if it did not find the character
            if char == nil or plr == player then continue end
            
            --cheacks if character is in attack radius or punchDistance
            if (char.PrimaryPart.Position - character.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude <= punchDistance then
                
                --calls hit finction
                coroutine.wrap(hit)(char, punchDamage)
                break
            end
        end
        
        --gets dummy thats being hit
        for _, dummy in workspace.dummies:GetChildren() do
            
            --checks if dummy is in range
            if (dummy.PrimaryPart.Position - character.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude <= punchDistance then
                
                --calls hit function
                coroutine.wrap(hit)(dummy, punchDamage)
                break
            end
        end



    end)
    
    -- waits for end of cooldown to continue
    task.spawn(function()
        task.wait(punchDebounceDuration)
        if punchDebounces[player] then
            punchDebounces[player] = nil
        end

    end)
end

replicatedStorage.punch.OnServerEvent:Connect(punch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To fix the fact that an animation is stopping half way through is to disable animation blending. You can do this by adding an boolean attribute to workspace called "RbxLegacyAnimationBlending" and set it to true.